# Filtering an associative array keys by regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex

How can I filter an associative array that takes one or more characters and matches that against the array keys using regex, and then returns the matched array?

Like we query the database:

```
select all from table-name where username LIKE %search%
```

I want to do the same with associative arrays.

I need to send an ajax call for every `keyup` event on the clientside. The server then takes that key, filters the array and sends back the results.

Comment: can you provide a short sample with input and expected output please. Thanks. In any case you are likely looking for the [array_intersect/diff](http://php.net/array_intersect) family of functions. Or [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) with a custom callback.

Answer (score 6):

Considering that you have an array like this:

```php
$haystack = [
    'foo'       => 123,
    'foobar'    => 234,
    'foobarbaz' => 345,
    'barbazfoo' => 456,
    'foobaz'    => 567,
];
```

You can filter the array by `foobar` key like this:

```php
$matches = preg_grep('/foobar/', array_keys($haystack))
// => [
//     1 => "foobar",
//     2 => "foobarbaz",
// ]
```

Now that you have the keys, you just need to reduce the original array:

```php
array_intersect_key($haystack, array_flip($matches))
// => [
//     "foobar" => 234,
//     "foobarbaz" => 345,
// ]
```

There are so many ways to do this. As reactivity is a concern in your case, you need to find the most performant way to do this.

To wrap it up as a function:

```php
function array_key_lookup($haystack, $needle)
{
    $matches = preg_grep("/$needle/", array_keys($haystack));

    return array_intersect_key($haystack, array_flip($matches));
}
```